# Pivoting date data

Tags: sql-server, pivot, firebird, interbase

How to join all different rows with the same ID but a different `DATE` and return it as a unique row with new columns like `DATE_0`, `DATE_1`, `DATE_2`, ...?

Consider this table:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | DATE       |
+----+------------+
| 0  | 01/12/2007 |
| 0  | 15/02/2018 |
| 1  | 21/05/2006 |
| 1  | 03/12/2017 |
| 1  | 01/03/2007 |
| 1  | 23/11/2018 |
| 2  | 15/10/2019 |
| 3  | 11/10/2019 |
| 3  | 22/07/2000 |
| 4  | 08/05/2001 |
| 4  | 07/03/1998 |
+----+------------+
```

I need a SQL query so this table will become like this:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID | DATE_0     | DATE_1     | DATE_2     | DATE_3     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 0  | 01/12/2007 | 15/02/2018 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 1  | 21/05/2006 | 03/12/2017 | 01/03/2007 | 23/11/2018 |
| 2  | 15/10/2019 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
| 3  | 11/10/2019 | 22/07/2000 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 4  | 08/05/2001 | 07/03/1998 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Keep in mind that I already know that the maximum number same ID rows wont exceed 4.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why have you marked this question as sql-sever, firebird, and interbase?

Comment: Please clarify what database this is being written for, as the answer will vary depending on the actual Database. Include version as well (since different versions of databases have different capabilities.)

Comment: Rather than close this question as unclear, I have pointed it at the canonical example Q & A. I also moved the rather long and specific title into the body. Please edit your question as others have requested. If the answer below and the canonical Q & A do not address your issue, please update your post to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: So this is called PIVOTING in SQL terminology, at least I know where I am floating now.

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese Actually it was intended for Firebird v2.5, but when I didn't see a variety of tags in this dba section, I added interbase and sql-server. But it is late now because someone posted a reply assuming sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have SQL SERVER as a base

You can try with this

```
DECLARE @HelpTable TABLE(
ID INT,
Fecha DATE
)

INSERT INTO @HelpTable VALUES (0,'2007/01/12'),
(0,'2018/02/15'),
(1,'2006/05/21')
,(1,'2017/12/03')
,(1,'2007/09/01')
,(1,'2018/11/23')



-- CTE TO GET THE VALUES 
    ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS N, A.Fecha as part ,ID AS IDReal
    FROM @HelpTable A
    )
--SELECT THE DATA
    SELECT IDReal,[1],[2],[3],[4]--[5],[6] etc
FROM(
    SELECT IDReal,part,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by IDReal ORDER BY IDReal) AS [rn]
    FROM CTE 
    ) AS [a] 
    --USE A PIVOT
    PIVOT(MAX(part) FOR [rn] IN([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS [pvt];
```

Do not fill in all the data but with that you can give yourself an idea I attach a link where you can see the example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73ef9d5cf770df291f4ed95d7a86d1a1